# Find the general solution to the differential equation, $y'+15x^{14}y = x^{15}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question ask me to use the variable $I=\int e^{x^{15}}dx$ when it occurs in my answer.

Here is my solution.

I let $P(x) = 15x^{14}$ and $Q(x) = x^{15}$ and a integrating factor $I(x) = e^{\int P(x)dx}$

so $I(x)$ will be $e^{x^{15}}$

and $y = \frac{\int e^{x^{15}} x^{15}dx + C}{e^{x^{15}}}$

But I don't know how to solve $\int e^{x^{15}} x^{15}dx$, I've tried to use integration by parts but seems not working.

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about if you write it like $$\int x\cdot x^{14}e^{x^{15}} dx$$

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks, I think I find the answer!